# Large sparse binary matrices with little row overlap

Tags: reference-request, coding-theory, applications

How can I construct sparse binary matrices $A : M \times N$, with ~ $N p$ ones in each row,
so that rows don't overlap much, i.e. the maximum

$\qquad \text{size} (\ A \text{ row } i \ \cap\  A \text{ row } j\ )$

over all pairs of rows is small ?
I'm looking for simple code or pseudocode, for small overlap -- not as small as possible.
Example sizes: $M = N = 1000000,\ p = 0.001$ .

(Generating a random matrix, then dropping rows with high overlap, might do the job. A systematic construction with some "Coding theory for dummies" would be nice though.)

Comment: permute the columns of the almost diagonal matrix (all the $1$ grouped the closest possible to the diagonal)

Comment: @user1952009, sorry, don't understand: column permutations don't change the size( row i $\cap$ row j ) ?

Comment: if $N = M$ and $N p \in \mathbb{N}$ then all the binary matrices minimizing the "overlap" are of the form I described, the idea being easily extended for the other cases.